# Virtualbox. Clipboard and shared folder in Ubuntu don't work

Tags: virtualbox, clipboard

I use Ubuntu 16 server as guest OS, Ubuntu 18.04 as host OS. I tried VirtualBox version 5.2.34 and 5.2.38.

I'm trying to setup shared folders and clipboard from host machine to guest one and all my attempts are vain.

After installation of Virtual box guest additions I enabled bidirectional clipboard and added shared folder, but it didn't work out.

I tried:

- added guest user to vboxsf user group
- have reinstalled Guest additions
- deleted and restored shared folders enabled and disabled clipboard
- upgraded VirtualBox to 5.2.38

Also I can't find guest additions for VirtualBox 5.2.38.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue these days and tried reinstalling guest additions on countless VMs without any results.

After some research, a bug was indeed present in VirtualBox 6.1.4 in which Shared Clipboard no longer works.

A new version has been released (6.1.6) in which the bug has been fixed.

From the Changelog: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog

> Shared clipboard: Multiple fixes including possible crash and HTML
>   data support

So i suggest you upgrade to version 6.1.6. And if it still doesn't work, downgrade to 6.1.2 instead because it still works there.